# Choose select option selected value in stripes based on passed object

Tags: jsp, stripes

In working with Stripes, I can very easily build a <select> dropdown with:

```
<s:options-collection collection="${bean.getter} value="id" sort="name"/>
```

How do I pre-select an initial value based on the object passed to the JSP?

Answer (score 1):

The 'value' attribute in the outer "s:select" tells it which one(s) to select.

```
<s:select name="..." value="xyz">
    <s:options-collection collection="${bean.getter} value="id" sort="name"/>
</s:select>
```

So any options matching "xyz" would be preselected.